# Do you know any article, book, resource that explains how Google makes its apps to work this FAST?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, optimization

Do you know any article, book, analyze etc. that focuses on strategies used by Google to make their applications (not the search but like Google Calender, Tasks, iGoogle etc.) to work this fast?

I am more interested the strategies they use to obtain quickly intractable web pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will help:

http://stevesouders.com/hpws/

Steve is an employee at google who works on Latency. He is also the mind behind Firefox YSlow. His set of rules are good read to consider for fast apps.

Answer (score 1):

No single book or resource may help you with that, I guess. Google is a combination of myriad of technologies with some of the best brains in the industries behind it.
To name a few

1. Compressing everything ( HTML, Javascript, CSS )
2. Google CDN
3. Powerful Servers that can handle many many requests simultaneously

Try View Source on http://www.google.com everything is compressed to its core.

If your aim is to built a faster loading website, this article is definitely worth a read.
[Performance is a Feature](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/06/performance-is-a-feature.html) by Jeff Attwood

Answer (score 0):

Google created their own tools that you might want to look at: [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/). You can check out the O'Reilly title: [Closure The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449381871) as well.

Comment: Closure is only one small piece in a very large, complex network of hardware and software.